# Filtering out the outdated items from table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, model

my application is built using ruby on rails, backed by mysql DB
It has 2 tables(models) - **product(id, name, created_at, updated_at, etc.) and product_details(id, product_type, product_id, expires_on, created_at, updated_at, etc.)** (connected by product ID column).

I need to select only those active records OR product_ids from product model/table which satisfy either of the following criteria - the product details for that particular product are out-dated/expired(expires_on column is present in product_details table) or there is no entry for that product in product_details table at all(valid scenario in my use case)

Please note that product_id is a foreign key which references product(id)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :product_detail
end
```

and

```
class ProductDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

You can use simple single-line query to fetch expired products or products without details:

```
Product.select { |p| p.product_detail.nil? || p.product_detail.expires_on <= Date.today }
```